# Has anyone been able to get the Go Hello World Quickstart demo to work for Google App Engine Managed VMs?

Tags: google-app-engine, go

I'm trying to follow the documentation [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/managed-vms/)

```
gcloud config set project <project>
gcloud components update app
gcloud components update gae-go
goapp get google.golang.org/appengine
# remove existing containers & images just to be sure
docker rm $(docker ps -a -q)
docker rmi $(docker images -q)
gcloud preview app setup-managed-vms
cd $GOPATH/src/google.golang.org/appengine/demos/helloworld
gcloud --verbosity debug preview app run --enable-mvm-logs .
```

Everything goes well up until the last line, which results in an "Internal error while starting instance":

`DEBUG: Running gcloud.preview.app.run with _Args({'admin_host': None,
 'allow_skipped_files': False,
 'api_host': None,
 'appidentity_email_address': None,
 'appidentity_private_key_path': None,
 'auth_domain': 'gmail.com',
 'blobstore_path': None,
 'clear_datastore': False,
 'dart_dev_mode': None,
 'dart_pub_serve_host': None,
 'dart_sdk': None,
 'datastore_consistency_policy': 'time',
 'datastore_path': None,
 'default_gcs_bucket_name': None,
 'docker_host': None,
 'enable_cloud_datastore': False,
 'enable_mvm_logs': True,
 'enable_sendmail': False,
 'format': None,
 'h': None,
 'help': None,
 'host': None,
 'jvm_flag': None,
 'log_level': None,
 'logs_path': None,
 'markdown': None,
 'max_module_instances': None,
 'modules': ['.'],
 'php_executable_path': None,
 'project': None,
 'python_startup_script': None,
 'quiet': None,
 'require_indexes': False,
 'shell': None,
 'show_mail_body': False,
 'smtp_allow_tls': False,
 'smtp_host': None,
 'smtp_password': None,
 'smtp_user': None,
 'storage_path': None,
 'use_mtime_file_watcher': False,
 'user_output_enabled': None,
 'verbosity': 'debug'}).
WARNING: The [application] field is specified in file [/home/dallan/test/testvm3/src/google.golang.org/appengine/demos/helloworld/app.yaml].  This field is not used by gcloud and should be removed.
DEBUG: Found Cloud SDK root: /home/dallan/tools/google-cloud-sdk
DEBUG: Found App Engine SDK root: /home/dallan/tools/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine
DEBUG: Command sys.path: ['/home/dallan/tools/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/lib/antlr3', '/home/dallan/tools/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/lib/fancy_urllib', '/home/dallan/tools/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/lib/ipaddr', '/home/dallan/tools/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/lib/yaml-3.10', '/home/dallan/tools/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/lib/rsa', '/home/dallan/tools/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/lib/pyasn1', '/home/dallan/tools/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/lib/pyasn1_modules', '/home/dallan/tools/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine', '/home/dallan/tools/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/lib/concurrent', '/home/dallan/tools/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/lib/cherrypy', '/home/dallan/tools/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/lib/distutils', '/home/dallan/tools/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/lib/requests', '/home/dallan/tools/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/lib/six', '/home/dallan/tools/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/lib/websocket', '/home/dallan/tools/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/lib/docker', '/home/dallan/tools/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/lib/jinja2-2.6', '/home/dallan/tools/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/lib/webob-1.2.3', '/home/dallan/tools/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/lib/webapp2-2.5.1', '/home/dallan/tools/google-cloud-sdk/./lib', '/home/dallan/tools/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/gcloud', '/home/dallan/tools/google-cloud-sdk/lib', '/usr/lib/python2.7/', '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload']
Module [default] found in file [/home/dallan/test/testvm3/src/google.golang.org/appengine/demos/helloworld/app.yaml]
DEBUG: Detected docker environment variables: DOCKER_HOST=tcp:// localhost:2376, DOCKER_CERT_PATH=/home/dallan/.docker, DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY=1
DEBUG: Sent event: Event(category='Executions', action='gcloud', label=u'2014.12.19', value=0)
INFO: Looking for the Dockerfile in /home/dallan/test/testvm3/src/google.golang.org/appengine/demos/helloworld
INFO: Using Dockerfile found in /home/dallan/test/testvm3/src/google.golang.org/appengine/demos/helloworld
DEBUG: Found Cloud SDK root: /home/dallan/tools/google-cloud-sdk
DEBUG: Found images: [u'gcloud-credentials-image:latest', u'google/appengine-log-server:latest', u'google/appengine-log-processor:latest', u'google/appengine-go:latest', u'google/appengine-java:latest', u'google/appengine-python27:latest', u'busybox:latest', u'google/docker-registry:latest']
DEBUG: Found image: google/appengine-go
DEBUG: Running [dev_appserver.py] with: --allow_skipped_files=False --application=metal-shift-360 --auth_domain=gmail.com --clear_datastore=False --datastore_consistency_policy=time --dev_appserver_log_level=debug --enable_cloud_datastore=False --enable_mvm_logs=True --enable_sendmail=False --log_level=debug --require_indexes=False --show_mail_body=False --skip_sdk_update_check=True --smtp_allow_tls=False --use_mtime_file_watcher=False /home/dallan/test/testvm3/src/google.golang.org/appengine/demos/helloworld/app.yaml
INFO: Skipping SDK update check.
INFO: Starting API server at: http:// localhost:49580
DEBUG: Detected docker environment variables: DOCKER_HOST=tcp:// localhost:2376, DOCKER_CERT_PATH=/home/dallan/.docker, DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY=1
DEBUG: Sent event: Event(category='Commands', action='gcloud.preview.app.run', label='unknown', value=0)
DEBUG: _add_watch_for_path('/home/dallan/test/testvm3/src/google.golang.org/appengine/demos/helloworld')
INFO: Looking for image_id for image with tag google/appengine-log-server
INFO: Creating container...
INFO: Container f243742e897d9c38c7c075bf7a6eedd3c054d68c356018c0268ba421dcab477f created.
INFO: Health checks starting for instance 0.
DEBUG: Performing health check for instance 0.
INFO: Starting Go VM Deployment process
INFO: Starting module "default" running at: http:// localhost:8080
DEBUG: Dispatching request to  after 0.0000s pending
INFO: Starting admin server at: http:// localhost:8000
DEBUG: Starting process ['/home/dallan/tools/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/goroot/bin/go-app-builder', '-app_base', '/home/dallan/test/testvm3/src/google.golang.org/appengine/demos/helloworld', '-arch', '6', '-dynamic', '-goroot', '/home/dallan/tools/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/goroot', '-nobuild_files', '^^$', '-unsafe', '-gopath', '/home/dallan/test/testvm3', '-print_extras', '-vm', 'helloworld.go'] with input='', env={'GOARCH': 'amd64', 'GOOS': 'linux'}, cwd=None
INFO: Go VM Deployment process failed: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer
ERROR: Internal error while starting instance.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/dallan/tools/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/module.py", line 1823, in _start_instance
    if not inst.start():
  File "/home/dallan/tools/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/instance.py", line 274, in start
    self._runtime_proxy.start()
  File "/home/dallan/tools/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/vm_runtime_proxy_go.py", line 130, in start
    self._vm_runtime_proxy.start(dockerfile_dir=dst_deployment_dir)
  File "/home/dallan/tools/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/vm_runtime_proxy.py", line 196, in start
    self._module_configuration.major_version, runtime_config.instance_id)
  File "/home/dallan/tools/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/log_manager.py", line 172, in add
    _create_table(l)
  File "/home/dallan/tools/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/log_manager.py", line 138, in _create_table
    response = conn.getresponse()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 1045, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 409, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 365, in _read_status
    line = self.fp.readline(_MAXLINE + 1)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 476, in readline
    data = self._sock.recv(self._rbufsize)
error: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer`

Any ideas what's going wrong?  `docker version` yields

```
Client version: 1.3.2
Client API version: 1.15
Go version (client): go1.3.3
Git commit (client): 39fa2fa
OS/Arch (client): linux/amd64
Server version: 1.3.2
Server API version: 1.15
Go version (server): go1.3.3
Git commit (server): 39fa2fa
```

and `go version` yields

```
go version go1.4 linux/amd64
```

A possible problem -- the Dockerfile generated by `gcloud preview app run` contains:

```
FROM google/appengine-go
..snip..
ADD . /app
RUN /bin/bash /app/_ah/build.sh
```

But when I shell into the google/appengine-go container directly using

```
docker run --rm -it --entrypoint /bin/bash google/appengine-go
```

I find that the /app directory is completely empty, and there isn't an _ah directory inside the helloworld application, so I'm not sure where /app/_ah/build.sh is supposed to be coming from. There isn't a build.sh file anywhere in the file system.

Any help is greatly appreciated. I've spent all day on this and I'm stumped.

Answer (score 0):

I made two changes and the Hello World demo app is finally working:

1. remove `application: helloworld` from app.yaml
2. modify the generated Dockerfile to insert `apt-get update &&` before `apt-get install`